# Make a cutom popup with darkened background in uwp with XAML c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, popup, windows-10-universal

I have made a few buttons for my admin page, for example-delete user, change info etc.. I want the window to darken once I click on one of the buttons, and then I want my own custom popup to appear(it will act like a small window), where I could, for example, enter values-the name of the user I want to delete for instance and then if I want to exit the popup, I will just have to click on the darkened background.

Technically, I could just achieve the same thing by making multiple windows and referencing to them on the click of each button, however, I think it will look unprofessional.
Does anyone know how can I achieve what I have just written? My biggest problem is with even creating a custom popup because so far I have only used the default dialog box.

I will be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my own custom popup to appear(it will act like a small window)

Did you tried to use  [ContentDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog)  ?

> if I want to exit the popup, I will just have to click on the darkened background.

Because of ContentDialogs are Modal dialog to achieve this you should use [PopUp Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) instead of ContentDialog.
Something like below source for XAML page then set its `IsOpen=true;` in code behind to show popup to user:

```
<Popup x:Name="popupDeleteUser"
   IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
   IsOpen="false">
   <Grid>
        Put your controls here
   </Grid>
</Popup>
```

> I want the window to darken once I click on one of the buttons

you can use [Blur animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/blur)